# expected unqualified-id before 'if' if (!client.connected() && lastConnected)

Tags: arduino-uno

```
#include <PulseSensorPlayground.h>
#include <Timer.h>
#include <SPI.h>
#include <Ethernet.h>


Timer t;
PulseSensorPlayground pulseSensor;

// Local Network Settings
byte mac[] = { 0xD4, 0x28, 0xB2, 0xFF, 0xA0, 0xA1 }; // Must be unique on local network
// ThingSpeak Settings
char thingSpeakAddress[] = "api.thingspeak.com";
String writeAPIKey = "UVGOLIA40B9YHKU8";
const int updateThingSpeakInterval = 16 * 1000; // Time interval in milliseconds to update ThingSpeak (number of seconds * 1000 = interval)
// Variable Setup
const int PulseWire = A0;       // PulseSensor PURPLE WIRE connected to ANALOG PIN 0
const int LED13 = 13;          // The on-board Arduino LED, close to PIN 13.
int Threshold = 550;           //for heart rate sensor
float myTemp;
int myBPM;
String BPM;
String temp;
int error;
int panic;
int raw_myTemp;
float Voltage;
float tempC;

long lastConnectionTime = 0;
boolean lastConnected = false;
int failedCounter = 0;
// Initialize Arduino Ethernet Client
EthernetClient client;
void setup()
{
  // Start Serial for debugging on the Serial Monitor
  Serial.begin(9600);
  pulseSensor.analogInput(PulseWire);
  pulseSensor.blinkOnPulse(LED13);       //auto-magically blink Arduino's LED with heartbeat.
  pulseSensor.setThreshold(Threshold);

  // Double-check the "pulseSensor" object was created and "began" seeing a signal.
  if (pulseSensor.begin()) {
    Serial.println("We created a pulseSensor Object !");  //This prints one time at Arduino power-up,  or on Arduino reset.
  }

  // Start Ethernet on Arduino
  void startEthernet();
}
void loop()
{
  // Read value from Analog Input Pin 0
  String analogPin0 = String(analogRead(A0), DEC);
  // Print Update Response to Serial Monitor
  if (client.available())
  {
    char c = client.read();
    Serial.print(c);
  }
  //temp---
  raw_myTemp = analogRead(A1);
  Voltage = (raw_myTemp / 1023.0) * 5000; // 5000 to get millivots.
  tempC = Voltage * 0.1;
  Serial.println(tempC);

  //Serial.print(temp);
  //Serial.print(" ");

  //-----BMP180-----------
  //
  int myBPM = pulseSensor.getBeatsPerMinute();  // Calls function on our pulseSensor object that returns BPM as an "int".
  // "myBPM" hold this BPM value now.
  if (pulseSensor.sawStartOfBeat()) {            // Constantly test to see if "a beat happened".

    Serial.println(myBPM);
    char buffer1[10];
    char buffer2[10];
    String BPM = dtostrf(myBPM, 4, 1, buffer1);
    String temp = dtostrf(tempC, 4, 1, buffer2);
    // Print the value inside of myBPM.
  }
}
//----------------
void panic_button() {
  panic = digitalRead(8);
  if (panic == HIGH) {
    Serial.println(panic);
  }
}
// Disconnect from ThingSpeak
if (!client.connected() && lastConnected)
{
  Serial.println("...disconnected");
  Serial.println();
  client.stop();
}
// Update ThingSpeak
if (!client.connected() && (millis() - lastConnectionTime > updateThingSpeakInterval))
{
  updateThingSpeak("field1=" + BPM + "&field2=" + temp + "&field3=" + panic);
}
// Check if Arduino Ethernet needs to be restarted
if (failedCounter > 3 ) {
  startEthernet();
}
lastConnected = client.connected();
}
void updateThingSpeak(String tsData)
{
  if (client.connect(thingSpeakAddress, 80))
  {
    client.print("POST /update HTTP/1.1\n");
    client.print("Host: api.thingspeak.com\n");
    client.print("Connection: close\n");
    client.print("X-THINGSPEAKAPIKEY: " + UVGOLIA40B9YHKU8 + "\n");
    client.print("Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded\n");
    client.print("Content-Length: ");
    client.print(tsData.length());
    client.print("\n\n");
    client.print(tsData);
    lastConnectionTime = millis();
    if (client.connected())
    {
      Serial.println("Connecting to ThingSpeak...");
      Serial.println();
      failedCounter = 0;
    }
    else
    {
      failedCounter++;
      Serial.println("Connection to ThingSpeak failed (" + String(failedCounter, DEC) + ")");
      Serial.println();
    }
  }
  else
  {
    failedCounter++;
    Serial.println("Connection to ThingSpeak Failed (" + String(failedCounter, DEC) + ")");
    Serial.println();
    lastConnectionTime = millis();
  }
}
void startEthernet()
{
  client.stop();
  Serial.println("Connecting Arduino to network...");
  Serial.println();
  delay(1000);
  // Connect to network amd obtain an IP address using DHCP
  if (Ethernet.begin(mac) == 0)
  {
    Serial.println("DHCP Failed, reset Arduino to try again");
    Serial.println();
  }
  else
  {
    Serial.println("Arduino connected to network using DHCP");
    Serial.println();
  }
  delay(1000);
}
```

Comment: You did not actually write a question!  Please edit

Answer (score 5):

If you look at this fragment of your code:

```
void panic_button(){
  panic = digitalRead(8);
    if(panic == HIGH){
    Serial.println(panic);
    }
}
// Disconnect from ThingSpeak
if (!client.connected() && lastConnected)
```

You see that the function panic_button() stops at the last }, the next is a statement which is not part of a function.

I think the } should be removed, but your code is aligned quite badly, so:

- First align all { and }
- Indent each level with a tab or 2, 3 or 4 spaces
- You will see a misalignment, add/remove a { (like above) or }.